# AWS RDS: tables disappear

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I use Amazon RDS PostgreSQL free tier. Periodically I find some tables deleted (last time there are the same tables). Probably it could be after automatic backups, but not sure because don't know the exact time when they disappear. Does someone have such problem or any idea how can I fix it?

PS: these tables are dependencies of other tables (I tried to delete them manually and was not able to because of relationships)

---

UPD:
Today this happened again but now all tables and sequences (only 1 remain) was deleted. In logs I've found the following:
`2023-09-23 04:00:08 UTC:101.36.106.49(47734):[unknown]@[unknown]:[22010]:LOG: invalid length of startup packet 2023-09-23 04:00:18 UTC:101.36.106.49(52710):[unknown]@[unknown]:[22021]:LOG: invalid length of startup packet 2023-09-23 04:00:19 UTC:101.36.106.49(54170):[unknown]@[unknown]:[22022]:FATAL: unsupported frontend protocol 65363.19778: server supports 3.0 to 3.0 2023-09-23 04:00:21 UTC:101.36.106.49(56122):versionprobe@versionprobe:[22024]:FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "101.36.106.49", user "versionprobe", database "versionprobe", no encryption`

Comment: I am confused, are these tables that you created?

Comment: Yes, this tables are created by me

Comment: Андрей Суручану -Bizarre, I have never seen this behavior.  Are you using Aurora or just plain Postgres?

Comment: I am using plain Postgres. Yes, for me this is also very strange and nothing found in google. (I'm using Stockholm region)

Comment: Change your password first, just to make sure no-one else is (ab)using your account.

Comment: The other obvious possibility is that you never committed the transaction that created the table, so that the table creation is rolled back when you close the database connection.